# How to add negative healing to a character temporarily?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, healing, player-characters, negative-energy

Beside [Undeath's Blessing](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=518), is there a way to add temporary negative healing to a character?

A potion or a divine spell would be best, but any solution is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Slim pickings

You could try *wish*. Not even that is clear, as there is no spell *currently* granting temporary undead status or negative healing, but it seems not out of range, power wise, if your GM agrees to it.

You also could get a Divine Intercession *boon from Urgotha*, that would grant you negative healing. Again, this is dependent on your GM cooperating.

> Moderate Boon: Urgathoa blesses you as one of her children. You gain negative healing.

Divine intercession manifests as a boon of varying duration, so this may not be as temporary as you might wish.

*Pierce the Veil* is a relic that allows you to do this with fine control (its not easy to pick up being a major gift, but neither are the others):

> While you are holding or wearing the relic, you have the negative healing ability (as though you were undead; positive energy harms you and negative energy heals you).

(Credit to this one goes to [Matthew Well's answer](https://While%20you%20are%20holding%20or%20wearing%20the%20relic,%20you%20have%20the%20negative%20healing%20ability%20(as%20though%20you%20were%20undead;%20positive%20energy%20harms%20you%20and%20negative%20energy%20heals%20you).), and it looks like the cleanest solution to me when it comes to control over how long it lasts).

Other than that, I don't think there currently are other effects that allow you to add *temporary* negative healing. You cannot polymorph into an undead as far as I can tell to gain the trait, and other options like becoming a Damphir or Lich seem way to permanent.

Answer (score 6):

[Pierce the Veil](https://2e.aonprd.com/Relics.aspx?ID=22) does exactly what you're looking for. It's not exactly easy to get though- it's a Major Gift, so you'll need a Death Aspect Relic to gain it, as well as being at least level 10 according to the recommended levels for advancing a relic. But if you can convince your GM to give you access to a Rare item *and* the right Gift, you're set.

Comment: I upvoted this, I think it is a clean solution, and the other ones I found are no easier to obtain either.